# OverWrite A Class Which Is Located Somewhere

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a page's structure where my code is at the bottom and above my code, there are a bunch of other codes from other pages which I don't have an access.

Let says class named `Name1` has background-color: green and I need to overwrite and change it to red color.

It looks like my overwrite doesn't work out.  How to make it work?  Please give me a hand.  Thanks!

Adding Note:  I did use developer tool to check it. When I inspected Name1, I don't see the style I wanted to overwrite. It looks like my style .Name1{background-color: red !important;} is local and  is global.  I wonder if JQuery will help to solve this issue?

Here is the page's structure

```
<html>
   <body>
       <table>
           <tr>
             <td>
                 <div class="Name1"></div>
             </td>
             ................
             ..................
             <td>
                  <html> <!--This is my session -->
                      <head>
                           <style>
                                  .Name1{background-color: red !important;}
                           </style>
                      </head>
                      <body>
                           <div>
                            ................
                           </div>
                      </body>
                  </html>
             </td>
       </table>
   </body>
```

Comment: The description sounds like coding chaos :-) "Code at the bottom and above code and a bunch of other codes"? Wha?

Comment: In general: more specific rules have priority, also later rules. Use your browsers development console to check their order and which rules apply, which are ignored.

Comment: To override an existing style, just make sure your `.Name{background-color: red !important}` is *after* the other one in the code. Sidenote: `<html>` and `<head>` inside of the `<td>` is unnecessary

Comment: I'm surprised you can have a nested `<html>...</html>` element. (Then again, most browsers won't complain anyhow.) I suspect that, instead of having your change pull a style like you're attempting, you'll need to use JavaScript to change the style on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Most elements can have a `style=` attribute.  For instance, `<a href="#myheader" style="text-decoration:none"></a>`, would remove the underline for the link.

This is called an in-line style.

Comment: Yep, and it is from the 80th. Depending on the headers such inline styles are ignored, too.

Comment: He says the element he wants to change is in a file he has no control over.

Comment: @Joe Sewell, you are right!  I have no access into the element I wanted to change.  Whatever I could do just happens inside my session and the element I want to change is in global.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, don't use inline styles, they're ugly and make for bad mark-up.

In your case, it is likely that another style is being applied to `.Name1` after you set your override style, you can easily check this by inspecting the source of your page with developer tools, analyse the `<head>` and check the order of which style sheets are included, you could also check the CSS pane and see which rules are being set for that element.

In order to remedy your problem (if you are not able to define your own stylesheet for whatever reason), you must use an inline style AFTER the `<head>` tag, directly on the element:

```
<div class="Name1" style="background-color: blue !important">
```

As I said above this is generally bad practice, but it will override the previous style due to the style being declared after the first style was applied this is because when the DOM renders its drawn top down:

```
============
Request Page
============
Begin Loading Page
============
    Load <head> Information    
         Traverse through <body> information and append it to the DOM 
============
End Loading Page
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for your concerns!  I did use developer tool to check it.  When I inspected `Name1`, I don't see any style I want to overwrite.  It looks like my style `.Name1{background-color: red !important;}` is local and `<div class="Name1"></div>` is global.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into an issue with CSS specificity. If a more specific definition is used elsewhere, it will use that over your definition.

[More about CSS Specificity.](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Can you provide a live example or real link that would show what classes and CSS sources are in play?

You can also use a tool like the web inspector in Chrome to see what rules are being used (in the styles tab, left column). Here is the web inspector for the text in your post above:
[image: web inspector example]
Notice how the `font-size` rule in `.post-text` is crossed out. This is being overridden by the `font-size` rule in the selector that is second from top. This is because this selector is considered "more specific" than the one inherited from it's parent (because it selects the element directly). In this way, you can see where each rule is coming from and why it is being chosen over other declartions for the same rule and element.